# Finding values of a, b, c of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find for which values of $a, b, c$ the following matrix is orthogonal

$$A=
  \left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & a & \frac{1}{2} \\
    \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} & b & \frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & c & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}  \\
  \end{array} } \right)$$

I was thinking of doing this: Need to find $u_1 \cdot u_2 = u_1 \cdot u_3 = u_2 \cdot u_3=0$ and that $u_4 \cdot u_4= 1$ which should form the orthogonal basis vectors but then I got stuck when I found $u_1 \cdot u_3 \neq 0$. Am I right or this is not the way to do this? Please help.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**: $A$ is orthogonal iff $A\cdot A^{T} = I$. You can work out the equations.

Comment: Is this how it should be solved? Why did you get a negative review?? :(

Comment: alright. thanks! :)

Comment: is it not $A^T \cdot A = I$?

Comment: Both are true. You might just use one of them.

Comment: I see they're just the same.. :) okay!

Comment: Is $A \cdot A^T$ just mere matrix multiplication? If yes, is it possible that $A \cdot A^T \neq I$? I've been manipulating and all but there are parts like $\frac{1}{2} \neq 0$ which are obviously not true.. or I just didn't get this $A \cdot A^T = I$ :(